# Accessing networked file locations with pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm trying to test a program using Python's `pathlib` module. With the `os` module, you used to be able to access networked drives by just following the same url-like form. But for some reason, you can't do this with `pathlib`. Or at least I can't figure out how to do it.

With the `os` module, all one would have to do is:

```
path = os.path.join(r'//server-01', 'directory', 'filename.txt')
```

But if you try to do this with the `pathlib` module, one could try something like:

```
path = Path('//server-01', 'directory', 'filename.txt')
```

If I'm on a Windows machine, path will resolve to:

```
>> WindowsPath('/server-01/directory/filename.txt)
```

And if I were to say `path.exists()` I will of course get `False`. Because yes, `/server-01` does NOT exist, however `//server-01` **does** exist.

Ideally of course, the result I expect to get when I run `path.exists()` is `True` and if I were to display `path` it would look something like:

```
>> WindowsPath('//server-01/directory/filename.txt')
```

**Update**

It's kind of hacky, but it works I guess, regardless I'd like to know the right way to do it.

In order to get to the network location you can:

```
os.chdir(join(r'//server-01', 'directory', 'filename.txt'))
path = Path()
path = path.resolve()
```

The result is something like:

```
>> WindowsPath('//server-01/directory/filename.txt')
path.exists()
>> True
```

If anyone knows the better way to do it, let me know.

Comment: Does `PureWindowsPath` work in this case?

Comment: It doesn't seem as though it does. I think the issue is that even in the documentation it says that it will collapse multiple slashes down into one no matter what you do. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) in one of that code blocks it demonstrates that. Seeing as the PureWindowsPath object inherits from PurePath it's going to have the same characteristics I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server name by itself is not a valid component of a UNC path. You must also include a share. So `path = Path('//server-01/directory', 'file')` will work. It should `resolve` and return `True` when you run `path.exists()`.

Microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dfsc/149a3039-98ce-491a-9268-2f5ddef08192

Answer (score 8):

If you create your path as:

```
path = Path('//server-01/directory/filename.txt')
```

instead of comma separating each directory it will work.

Answer (score 3):

after several attempts, I think you can visit the smb folder/file with `pathlib` by:

```
folder = pathlib.Path('//server/')

file = pathlib.Path('//server/') / 'relative/path/to/file'
# or
file = pathlib.Path('//server/relative/path/to/file')
```

the key is that if you want to visit a smb folder, the arg should end with '/'.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating `path` as a `PureWindowsPath` should do the trick:

```
path = PureWindowsPath("//server-01", "directory", "file") # '\\\\server-01\\directory\\file'
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I tried that and it still resolves to a single forward slash.